# iPhone Shell, reading output

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

For executing a shell command I'm using `system("ls");` command. Is there any way I can read the output?

Comment: You can't execute a shell command in iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on the iPhone since there is no shell. On a standard POSIX system (like OS X on the desktop) you would either use popen, or set up a pipe between your app and the child process manually using fork, exec, and pipe.

If you actually want to list the contents of a directory, use NSFileManager.